# Why can ssh read my password when stdin is already used up?

Tags: linux, ssh, tty

For example, the following command works:

```
$ cat some-file | md5sum
8981da1a6a4838c915e333820640d213  -
$ cat some-file | ssh user@host "md5sum"
user@host's password:
8981da1a6a4838c915e333820640d213  -
```

Why ssh is able to get user's password? I assumed that it read password from stdin, but it clearly is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tty is the answer, it reads from /dev/tty. A program can write to it too, apart from stdout.